# Maintain plot size with annotations in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to trying to combine 4 ggplots with common x and y axes and a common legend. [Here's what I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6KyX.jpg). The problem is that adding the annotations for the common axes alters the size of the columns and rows such that the second row plots are slightly shorter and the second column plots are slightly wider (I guess technically actually the annotations are included in the column/row and so the graph has to shrink accordingly). It's not enough to be an issue, but it's annoying and I'd like to keep them all the same size. An additional minor annoyance is that the addition of the common legend means the common x axis title is aligned to the middle of the graphic, rather than the middle of the plots - is that fixable?

```
plot.conf<-ggarrange(plot.jm,plot.am,plot.jf,plot.af,common.legend = TRUE, legend="right",widths=1,heights=1)

plot.conf<-annotate_figure(plot.conf, 
  left=text_grob("Probability of correct identification",rot=90),
  bottom=text_grob("Confidence (%)"))
plot.conf
```

For interest, A is juvenile males, B is adult males, C is juvenile females and D is adult females.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please look at making a reproducible example. You might like to look at one of these packages: patchwork or cowplot.

Comment: Judging from your plots, you could probably manage this by using facets. Otherwise, the patchwork suggestion from Mark is a good one.

Comment: Thanks both. I have used patchwork before, but couldn't find an option to produce common axes. The available annotations are more based around titles/subtitles/tags. I only used ggarrange this time as it had the option for this style of annotation.